# Should not most of the CW questions be closed, or locked?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

There are [88 CW questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1%20is:question&submit=search); of those, [75 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1%20is:question%20closed:0&submit=search) are not closed.
Should not they be closed, or locked? As I can see, there are many questions that should not be asked, basing on the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq), as they are not asked because an actual problem, such as:

- [What are some of the better English reference grammars?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183/what-are-some-of-the-better-english-reference-grammars)
- [What is the longest word you can come up with that the letters are all in alphabetical order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/what-is-the-longest-word-you-can-come-up-with-that-the-letters-are-all-in-alphab)
- [What mnemonics help solve common linguistic issues?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/what-mnemonics-help-solve-common-linguistic-issues)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/comical-examples-of-abused-apostrophes
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/memorable-no-pun-intended-sentences-used
- [Is there an online sample sentence database or search engine?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/is-there-an-online-sample-sentence-database-or-search-engine)

While such CW questions were once acceptable, now that the purpose of CW questions has been re-defined, those questions should be closed, or locked with a notice that those questions are not anymore acceptable, and they should not taken as example of questions user can ask on EL&U.

Comment: Can you give a link to where was the purpose of CW question re-defined?

Comment: [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).